# Sending values of a form with ajax via post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

im trying to send values in a form via POST in ajax, how do i capture them in send them, this is wat i have now while in GET

```
    function test(ans_field_uuid){
        var result = "";
        var url="ajax_pages/remove_answer_field_ajax.php"
        url += '?uuid=' + ans_field_uuid;
        $.get(
        url,
        function (data) {
            result = data;
        }
    )
        .success(function () {
            if (result != "") {
                addTableRow('tb_add_field', result);
                $('#ajaaxDiv').html(result);
            }
        })
        .complete(function () {
            $('#img_create_subcat').hide();
            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        })
        .error(function () {
            alert('An error has occurred.');
        });
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Just change `.get` to `.post`?

Comment: Check the `$.post` method: http://docs.jquery.com/Post ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you already use jQuery

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

data: name and location are your POST variable.
You can fetch the POST variable in this example in some.php with

```
$_POST["name"]
```

which equals "John"

If you want to receive something then like "Hello".
Inside your some.php

```
echo "Hello";
```

and it will be send to your ajax function as response in your done function as variable msg

Comment: how can i create a loading image in this situation?, while the ajax page loads

Comment: http://www.linein.org/blog/2010/05/12/jquery-ajax-loading-display-images-or-text-until-script-is-finished-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
// ...

var url = "ajax_pages/remove_answer_field_ajax.php";

$.post( url, "uuid=" + ans_field_uuid, function (data) {
    result = data;
}
// ...
```